# Copy build folder to my repository

Tags: node.js, docker, repository, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have this bitbucket-pipelines.yml, is there any way to copy the build that is created by `npm run buid` into my repository?

```
image: node:6.9.4

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
         caches:
          - node
         script:
          - npm install
          - npm run build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean saving the build as a Download in your Bitbucket repository, then we have [a guide on how to do it via the Bitbucket API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-build-artifacts-to-bitbucket-downloads-872124574.html). The basic steps are:

1. Create an app password for the repository owner
2. Create a Pipelines environment variable with the authentication token
3. Upload your artifacts to Bitbucket Downloads using curl and the Bitbucket REST API

The details of how to do this are covered [in the guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/deploy-build-artifacts-to-bitbucket-downloads-872124574.html).

If you mean committing the build back to the Git repository, we wouldn't recommend that. Storing build output in Git isn't ideal - you should use BB downloads or an npm registry for that. But if you really want to, you can do it by following the guide above to create an app password, then pass it as an environment variable into Pipelines, set it in a HTTPS git remote, then use `git push` to upload it back to Bitbucket.